# get elements in one array while not in other array along with axis 0

Tags: numpy

there is 2 arrays with same number of columns but different number of rows:

```py
arrA = np.array(np.arange(8)).reshape(8, 1)
A = np.repeat(a=arrA, repeats=4, axis=0)
# (32, 1)

arrB = np.array(np.arange(4)).reshape(4, 1)
B = np.tile(A=arrB, reps=(8, 1))
# (32, 1)

D = 370
arrC = np.array([[i+D*4] for i in range(4)])
C = np.tile(A=arrC, reps=(8, 1))
# (32, 1)

arrD = np.array(D)
D = np.tile(A=arrD, reps=(8*4, 1))
# (32, 1)

arr_0 = np.hstack((A, B, C, D))
# (32, 4)
```

and

```py
arr_1 = np.array([[3, 0, 1480, 370], [3, 2, 1482, 370]])
# (2, 4)
```

arry_0 and arry_1 both are somehow like an array of locations;

what I expect to get:

```
[[   0    0 1480  370]
 [   0    1 1481  370]
 [   0    2 1482  370]
 [   0    3 1483  370]
 [   1    0 1480  370]
......
 [   2    3 1483  370]
 [   3    1 1481  370]
 [   3    3 1483  370]
......
 [   7    0 1480  370]
 [   7    1 1481  370]
 [   7    2 1482  370]
 [   7    3 1483  370]]
...

# shape (30, 4)
```

I‘ve tried with `np.intersect1d(arr_0, arr_1)`, but it tends to output the intersections...

```py
[   0    2    3  370 1480 1482]
# shape (1, 6)
```

This is not what I would like to see

2022/2/19 Update:

to get expected results, refer to the methods in the post mentioned below:

```
Av = np.ascontiguousarray(arr_0).view(np.dtype([('', arr_0.dtype, arr_0.shape[1])])).ravel()
Bv = np.ascontiguousarray(arr_1).view(Av.dtype).ravel()
X = arr_0[np.isin(Av, Bv, invert=True)]
# X.shape -> (30, 4)
```

Comment: ```NameError: name 'xblk' is not defined``` error while running your code. Can you also explain what is ```ch```, ```lun``` etc.

Comment: @Lawhatre sorry for the confusion. I've updated my code. as for ```ch```, ```lun```, they're just names of variables defined by me....

Comment: I don't really understand the logic here. All the rows in `arr_0` are of the general format `[   0,    0, 1480,  370]`. You want the rows from `arr_0` where all the values are in any arbitrary column of `arr_1`?

Comment: @CJR so, ```arr_0.shape``` is ```(96, 4)```, and ```arr_1.shape``` is ```(2, 4)```. after subtracting elements in ```arr_0``` based on ```arr_1```, the shape of output should be ```(94, 4)```

Comment: You want to remove the rows in `arr_0` which exactly match rows in `arr_1`? That's not an intersection.

Comment: @CJR hey, I have to say the purpose of this post is the same with the post you mentioned above. However, I tried with the method in that post and did not get the expected result (an array with elements in ```arr_0``` and not in ```arr_1```, ```shape (94, 4)```, as attached in the description of this post.

Comment: `arr_0` has four copies of each of the rows in `arr_1` and all four are removed. If you want to only remove the first copy of a row that appears in `arr_1` you'll have to modify this code.

Comment: @CJR thx for your tip and I've updated this post with my results in case someone else come across similar question.